# Adaptive Metropolis For Multidimensional Parameter

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process

Hi recently I want to implement the adaptive Metropolis algorithm. However I dont know how to deal with multidimensional parameters. The normal step of the [adaptive MCMC](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/sail/readings/andrieu-thoms.pdf) is to update the covariance matrix of the parameters, which are usually scalar or vector. But what if I want to estimate the precision/covariance matrix in the multivariate normal distribution which is $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$? The parameter has dimension $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. So I have several idea:

1. Flatten the parameter and use a $\mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n^2}$ matrix for adaptive MCMC, which is computational demanding.
2. Treat this parameter as a *scalar* and use a scalar step size. But I need to design several if-else to check the dimension of the parameters.

Could anyone help me in this case? This should have a answer but I did not find after search.. Thanks!